# Understanding how aload_0 and iload_0 work

Tags: java, constructor, jvm, bytecode

I'm learning more about how to read Java bytecode, and it's very interesting. From my understanding, every stack frame gets its own array of variables. So, do all types (`int` or a reference) share this same array?

```
public class ByteTest {
    private int thisField;

    public ByteTest(int f){
        thisField = f;
    }
}
```

In this code, `iload_1` suggests that there is already a value in the `0th` spot, but `f` is obviously the first *`int`* variable in this block of code, except for the fact that `this` is the first *reference* variable in this stack. So, all types share this same array? Am I correct in my reasoning? This is the bytecode for the constructor

```
/* L4 */
0 aload_0;                /* this */
1 invokespecial 10;       /* java.lang.Object() */
/* L5 */
4 aload_0;                /* this */
5 iload_1;                /* f */
6 putfield 13;            /* .thisField */
/* L6 */
9 return;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are correct. A stack frame shares one set of local variables for all types. See also [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1) from the JVM specification:

> Each frame (§2.6) contains an array of variables known as its *local variables*. The length of the local variable array of a frame is determined at compile-time and supplied in the binary representation of a class or interface along with the code for the method associated with the frame (§4.7.3).
>
> A single local variable can hold a value of type `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `float`, `reference`, or `returnAddress`. A pair of local variables can hold a value of type `long` or `double`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all types share the same array. The best way to think of it is that you have an array of up to 65535 slots where you can store any variable you want (though longs and doubles take up two slots each). You can even store values of multiple different types in the same slot during different parts of the method. When the class is loaded, the JVM does static analysis on the bytecode to make sure that you always load a value as the same type that it was originally stored.

So the following is valid

```
iconst_0
istore_0
iload_0
aconst_null
astore_0
aload_0
```

But the following is invalid

```
iconst_0
istore_0
aload_0
```

Note that this is true for Java bytecode. Dalvik bytecode has similar but distinct rules for type checking. For example, constants in Dalvik are untyped, as are move instructions, so the Dalvik equivalent of the second example would pass verification.